# Custom Package Library breaks web.config of main project

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-package

I have a custom .Net Framework library including following packages:

```
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.2.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.6" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.6" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.6" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.6" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens" version="5.3.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" version="5.3.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" version="5.3.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="MitarbeiterPackage" version="1.0.0.12" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="11.0.2" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="NuGet.Client" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net471" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="NuGet.CommandLine" version="4.7.1" targetFramework="net471" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="NuGet.Common" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net471" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="NuGet.ContentModel" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net471" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="NuGet.Frameworks" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net471" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="NuGet.Packaging" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net471" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="NuGet.Packaging.Core" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net471" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="NuGet.Packaging.Core.Types" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net471" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="NuGet.Repositories" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net471" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="NuGet.RuntimeModel" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net471" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="NuGet.Versioning" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net471" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" version="5.3.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Security.Claims" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net471" />
</packages>
```

We also have a private NuGet-Server running where we push all that libraries. The problem now is, that when I install this package to any main project, it breaks the total web.config. Breaks means, that it removes `configSections`, `system.data`, `oracle.manageddataaccess.client` and some parts of `system.web` .

Does anyone has an idea why and how I can stop that? All our other packages works well. Only that one makes the problems.

Comment: Did you check that this package doesn't actually have a *.ps1 file included that is executed when you install the package and that performs these changes?

Comment: Unfortunaltly not. Is is possible, that one of the installed packages have a *.ps1 file?